# What does $\int_0^\infty 1_{[X>t]}dt$ mean? X is a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

What does $$\int_0^\infty 1_{[X>t]}dt$$ mean? X is a random variable. If X is a r.v., then so does $1_{[X>t]}$. Thus this is the integral of random variables on t. I think it may be defined in Stochastic Process or something, can anyone tell me its definition or give me a reference link? Thank you ahead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the random variable $Y$ defined by the condition that, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$,
$$
Y(\omega)=\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{[X(\omega)\gt t]}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Exercise: Check that $Y=\max(X,0)$.